# Referencing SQLiteCommand class not valid when embedding interop type

Tags: .net, vb.net, dll, interop

I'm distributing `System.Data.Sqlite.dll` which I integrated into my project using NUGET.

I'm releasing my application as x86.

If I simply distribute System.Data.Sqlite.dll to my application folder, my application crashes.

When I distribute the file "SQLite.Interop.dll", which VS places into bin\x86\Release\x86\ at compile time, my application doesn't crash anymore, and everything works fine.

However, I don't want to distribute the Interop dll.
Therefore I right-click the reference System.Data.Sqlite in my solution and set "Embed Interop Type" to "True".

Now Visual Studio doesn't want to compile my application anymore, telling me

> A reference to SQLiteCommand class isn't valid when the assembly is configured to embed Interop types.

Do I really have to distribute Sqlite.Interop.dll, or can I solve this is an elegant way?

Comment: You can download *bundle* package from [here](http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/downloads.wiki). Them contains mixed-mode assembly which embed native components in managed assembly.

Answer (score 0):

if we are setting "Embed Interop Type" to "False" it will work fine.

otherwise refer this [document](https://www.boxedapp.com/boxedappsdk/usecases/embed_system.data.sqlite.dll_dependencies.html)

Answer (score 0):

Use the SQLitePCL*.* nugets (SQLitePCL.raw for .net 4.0 support).